# Firefox Not implementing full style sheet

Tags: css, firefox

I'm having a bit of an issue with Firefox. I have implemented the following rule:

```
h1.entry-title {    
    font-family: "meddon"; color:white;
    padding: 10px 0 25px 0;
    margin: 0px;        
    background-image: url(images/backgrounds/h1.png) no-repeat bottom 0px; 
}
```

Yet in Firefox it doesn't show fully. Using Firebug, it shows an incomplete rendition of this style. The following is rendered:

```
h1.entry-title {
    color: white;
    font-family: "meddon";
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 25px;
}
```

Not sure why the other declarations are not showing up, ie, the background image is not there. Also note that padding should have 4 numbers not three. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
h1.entry-title {
         font-family: "meddon"; 
         color:white; 
         padding:10px 0 25px 0;
         margin: 0px;
         background:#fff url("images/backgrounds/h1.png") no-repeat bottom }
```

Comment: that was it, I think, had a weird background positioning!

Comment: Hey, it happens when you write markup. Glad to have helped you figure out a solution. Please make sure you mark mine as your answer :) @ Driftwood

Comment: the `background` property here will set the `background-position` to `center bottom`, rather than `left bottom` as the OP specified. `0px bottom` is also a valid rule. The `background-position` was not part of the original issue.

Answer (score 4):

`background-image` only takes an image source, not a list of parameters.  You're looking for just plain `background`

[Here's a link to the background property](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background)

As for the padding, the 3 parameter syntax translates to top, right & left, bottom.  The four number syntax translates to top, right, bottom, left.  So it's doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

because you used an invalid `background-image` value, the style will not show up.

As for the padding, firebug uses abbreviations whenever possible:

```
padding: all;
padding: top/bottom left/right;
padding: top left/right bottom;
padding: top right bottom left;
```